# My dapp doesn't detect when an user change their Metamask Account

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, metamask, ethers.js

I am in the process of building a dapp for a project. I have one last thing to adjust: detect when a user changes metamask account to reset the state but it doesn't work.

```js
//Doesn't work
window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
    console.log('accountsChanges', accounts);
    setDefaultAccount(null);
});

// This works perfectly
window.ethereum.on('chainChanged', (chainId) => {
    if(chainId !== "0x13881") {
        setErrorMessage("Please connect on testnet Polygon Mumbai");
    } else {
        setErrorMessage(null);
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. this is a syntax error. maybe u are not closign function properly

Answer (score 3):

I was also struggling with the same issue. Being unable to find the answer in the docs anywhere.
Until I'd realized that it's not meant to detect you switching from a connected account to a disconnected one.

In other words: it only detects it when you switch between accounts that are already connected to your Dapp. In that case - it functions perfectly. And detects an account change.

Go on ahead an test it on some popular Dapp out there. Connect just one of your accounts to it - then change it to another account on the same wallet, that is not yet connected - and it will also not be able to detect you changing it.
But if you connect two accounts right away - it will detect you switching between them and reflect your changes on its interface.

I tested this with PCS.

Answer (score 2):

this is the correct way of implementation:

```
useEffect(() => {
      ethereum?.on("accountsChanged", handleAccountChange);
      return () => {
        ethereum?.removeListener("accountsChanged", handleAccountChange);
      };
    });
```

Now write a listener for account change

```
const handleAccountChange = (...args) => {
      // you can console to see the args
      const accounts = args[0] ;
      // if no accounts that means we are not connected
      if (accounts.length === 0) {
        console.log("Please connect to metamask");
        // our old data is not current connected account
        // currentAccount account that you already fetched and assume you stored it in useState
      } else if (accounts[0] !== currentAccount) {
        // if account changed you should update the currentAccount so you return the updated the data
        // assuming you have [currentAccount,setCurrentAccount]=useState
        // however you are tracking the state currentAccount, you have to update it. in case of redux you have to dispatch update action etc
        setCurrentAccount(accounts[0)
      }
    };
```